# Magento 2 problem with script (map - INPOST ) in checkout - Shipping method

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

I am trying to add my new shipping method with a map (INPOST) but I have a problem. My map won't load. Then I try to use a case with no map, with points but still not working in the checkout. I tried to do this on the product page and it worked.

My custom shipping method working good, only problem with that map

Documentation: https://docs.inpost24.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7798862

Magento version: 2.3

Bellow my codes:

**app/code/Kitsune/Inpost/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js"  src_type="url" async="async"/> 
    <css src="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/css/easypack.css"  src_type="url"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                         
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                                          
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingMethodItemTemplate" xsi:type="string">Kitsune_Inpost/custom-method-item-template</item>
                                                        <item name="shippingMethodListTemplate" xsi:type="string">Kitsune_Inpost/custom-method-list-template</item>                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Kitsune/Inpost/view/frontend/web/js/inpost.js**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  easyPack.init({            
      instance: 'pl',
      mapType: 'osm',
      searchType: 'osm',
      points: {
        types: ['parcel_locker'],
      },
      map: {
        useGeolocation: true,
        initialTypes: ['parcel_locker']
      }
    })
    window.onload = function() {
      easyPack.dropdownWidget('easypack-widget', function(point) {
        console.log(point)
      });
    }       
});
```

**app/code/Kitsune/Inpost/view/frontend/web/template/custom-method-item-template.html**

```
<!-- Initialize collapsible binding -->
<tbody collapsible="as: '$collapsible_' + method.method_code">
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="col col-method">
            <input type="radio"
                   class="radio"
                   click="element.selectShippingMethod"
                   ifnot="method.error_message"
                   ko-checked="element.isSelected"
                   ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
                   attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                        'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
        </td>
        <td class="col col-price">
            <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
        </td>
        <td class="col col-method"
            attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
            text="method.method_title" />
        <td class="col col-carrier"
            attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
            text="method.carrier_title" />
        <!-- Column with collapsible trigger  -->
        <td class="col">
                    <!-- ko if: method.carrier_code == 'kitsune_inpost' -->
                        <div data-bind="mageInit: {'inpost': {}}" id="easypack-widget"></div>
                        <h1>eloo</h1>
                    <!-- /ko -->
      
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Row for shipping method description -->
    <tr class="row" visible="$context['$collapsible_' + method.method_code].opened">
        <td class="col" colspan="5" i18n="'Some description.'"/>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row row-error"
        if="method.error_message">
        <td class="col col-error" colspan="5">
            <div role="alert" class="message error">
                <div text="method.error_message"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="no-display">
                <input type="radio"
                       attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**app/code/Kitsune/Inpost/view/frontend/web/template/custom-method-list-template.html**

```
<div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
    <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method" markdown="1"> <thead>
        <tr class="row" markdown="1">
            <th class="col col-method" translate="'Select Method'" />
            <th class="col col-price" translate="'Price'" />
            <th class="col col-method" translate="'Method Title'" />
            <th class="col col-carrier" translate="'Carrier Title'" />
            <!-- Column for triggers -->
            <th class="col" />
        </tr>
        </thead>  <!-- tbody was moved inside item template --> <!-- ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'} --> <!--ko template: { name: element.shippingMethodItemTemplate} --><!-- /ko --> <!-- /ko --> </table>
</div>
```

**app/code/Kitsune/Inpost/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            inpost: 'Kitsune_Inpost/js/inpost'            
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add just comment instead of posting an answer (but I can't comment).

Wrap your js in define and check comments I added here:

```js
define(['domReady!'], function() {
    // check here via debugger if code is executed
    // then you can investigate why rest isn't working
    window.easyPack.init({
        instance: 'pl',
        mapType: 'osm',
        searchType: 'osm',
        points: {
          types: ['parcel_locker'],
        },
        map: {
            useGeolocation: true,
            initialTypes: ['parcel_locker']
        }
    });
    // this also won't work as you can miss onload event
    window.onload = function() {
        easyPack.dropdownWidget('easypack-widget', function(point)         
    {
            console.log(point)
        });
    };
});
```

2. you need be sure that easyPack will be available. Do you load it synchronously? I see some async version in documentation so you need to think about that and implement it properly.

Comment: Yes, i load it asynchronously
in head i have this:
`<script src="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js"  src_type="url" async="async"/>`
with param async="async"